# How to use html formatting I am getting from a Json Web Response?

Tags: java, json, jsp, jspx

I am using a Hotel Api Provider that is sending as a Json response back to my application a Json Node that contains a string.
Inside that string the provider is using some html formatting like this :

```
"shortDescription": "<p><b>Location. </b> <br />The Edgewater - A Noble House Hotel is a business-friendly hotel located in central Seattle, close to Odyssey - The Maritime Discovery Center, Washington State Convention &"
```

When I am trying to use this field in my jspx page , inside a table cell, I get the raw text without formatting and with all the paragraph and bold tags.
Is there any way I can force my jspx page to display this formatting?
Thank you.

Comment: Please show the code you are using to assign the 'shortDescription' to the 'table cell' in your page.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to replace old content with new content. You can use `jQuery.replaceWith` for that.

When you get the response JSON you can, for example, replace the row under question with a new row containing new data:

```
var rep = "<tr id='id-to-replace'><td>Description</td><td>" + responseJSON.description + "</td></tr>";
$('#id-to-replace').replaceWith(rep);
```